Unable to remove "SHAPE" from field list
I'm trying to list the fields of a feature class and then remove certain fields from that list, using a for loop, so that it can be used in a delete field tool. I have a list of fields I want to keep, one of them being "SHAPE", but the for loop removes every other field name except "SHAPE". I've tried different variations of the word; like SHAPE, Shape, @SHAPE, and SHAPE@. None of them work unfortunately. The SHAPE field has a Geometry field type.
blocksLayer = arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(r"\\data\root\Blocks_All_States_Themed.lyr", r"memory\Blockslayer")
keepFields = ["LICENCE_ID", "BLOCK_ID", "UBI", "CUTB_BLOCK_STATE", "OBJECTID", "SHAPE"]
deleteFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.Describe(blocksLayer).fields]
for field in deleteFields:
    if field in keepFields:
        deleteFields.remove(field)
        AddMsg("removing " + field)
AddMsg(deleteFields)
arcpy.management.DeleteField(blocksLayer, deleteFields)

The code above returns the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\tst_root\GIS_WORKSPACE\Projects\Google_Earth\PythonScript\main3.py", line 49, in <module>
    arcpy.management.DeleteField(blocksLayer, deleteFields)
  File "E:\sw_nt\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6099, in DeleteField
    raise e
  File "E:\sw_nt\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\management.py", line 6096, in DeleteField
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.DeleteField_management(*gp_fixargs((in_table, drop_field, method), True)))
  File "E:\sw_nt\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 520, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 002557: Cannot delete field SHAPE from memory\Blockslayer.
Failed to execute (DeleteField).

The following is the print out from the "AddMsg" functions. You can see that all of the keepFields are removed except SHAPE, and then looking at the final list you can see SHAPE at the top:
Setting workspace and variables...
Preparing block layer...
removing OBJECTID
removing LICENCE_ID
removing BLOCK_ID
removing UBI
removing CUTB_BLOCK_STATE
['SHAPE', 'DIVI_DIV_NBR', 'TSO_CODE', 'TSO_NAME', 'FIELD_TEAM', 'MANU_ID', 'TENURE', 'PERMIT_ID', 'MARK_ID', 'BLOCK_NBR', 'OPENING', 'OP_AREA', 'OPAR_OPERATING_AREA_NAME', 'OZON_OPERATING_ZONE_ID', 'SUPPLY_BLOCK', 'EBM_INDICATOR', 'PHOTO', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE', 'PROV_FRST_CONFLICT', 'MAPSHEET_ID', 'LANDSCAPE_UNIT', 'SP_EXEMPT', 'STAND_TYPE', 'AGE_CLASS', 'HGT_CLASS', 'STK_CLASS', 'SITE_INDEX', 'SOURCE', 'FDP_STATUS', 'FUNDING_CODE', 'CUTB_BLOCK_MEMO', 'GROSS_AREA', 'EST_AREA', 'MERCH_AREA', 'HARVEST_AREA', 'REMAINING_AREA', 'CRUISE_VOL', 'HARVEST_VOL', 'REMAINING_VOL', 'BLAL_USR_CRUISE_M3_VOL', 'RW_AREA', 'RW_VOL', 'CUTB_FORMA_PRINT_DATE', 'CUTB_FORMA_PRINTED', 'PMOD_MODIFIER_ID', 'CUTB_LOCATION', 'SUOP_SUBOP_AREA_ID', 'SUBOP_AREA_NAME', 'CUTB_OPENING_ID', 'LICN_LICENCE_STATE', 'SEED_ZONE', 'CUTB_FILE_ID', 'MIN_ELEVATION', 'MAX_ELEVATION', 'BCAT_CATEGORY_CODE', 'CUTB_ACCESS_RESTRICTION', 'REGIME_CREATED_BY', 'TREG_REGIME_ID', 'TREG_REGIME_NAME', 'TREG_CREATE_DATE', 'TREG_ACTIVE_IND', 'TREG_DEF_IND', 'FIZ', 'HVS_STATUS', 'HVS_TARGET_DATE', 'HVS_STATUS_DATE', 'HVC_STATUS', 'HVC_TARGET_DATE', 'HVC_STATUS_DATE', 'MANU_SEQ_NBR', 'LICN_SEQ_NBR', 'PERM_SEQ_NBR', 'MARK_SEQ_NBR', 'CUTB_SEQ_NBR', 'CUTB_CPRP_PROTECTION_IND', 'CUTB_RC_RISK_RATING', 'CUTB_RC_RISK_SOURCE', 'SHAPE_AREA', 'SHAPE_LEN']


As commented by @MichaelStimson - case is important, use .upper().
Try the following instead to use a list comprehension and save using a loop block:
deleteFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.Describe(blocksLayer).fields if f.name.upper() not in keepFields]

You probably also want to check if the field is required
deleteFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.Describe(blocksLayer).fields if f.name.upper() not in keepFields and not f.required]


I'm surprised the solution works if OP wants to get rid of SHAPE field in a Layer, the SHAPE should be required....though I like how you avoid the concern by testing f.required!

@JasonInVegas the OP didn't want to get rid of the shape field.  The OP was trying to keep it.

Ya, my bad...their code removed the field from the remove list then printed "Removed" got me turned around
